# populate expandablelistview through json

Tags: android

After populating expandablelistview using json array, I am having problem in showing specific child to specific header. Right now all child are combined and being showed under every header.

My activity code is

```
package com.example.admin_pc.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Admin-PC on 6/8/2017.
 */

class ExpandableListAdapter3  extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Parent_Bean> groups;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Child_Bean>> child;
    int count;
    String str;

    public ExpandableListAdapter3(Context context, ArrayList<Parent_Bean> groups, ArrayList<ArrayList<Child_Bean>> child) {
        this.context = context;
        this.groups = groups;
        this.child=child;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){return true;}



    @Override
    public Child_Bean getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        /*ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();*/
        return child.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
        //return chList.get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        Child_Bean child_obj=getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
        VHolder holder=null;
        if(convertView==null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, null);
            holder = new VHolder();
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date_txt);
            holder.loc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.location_txt);

            holder.mesg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_txt);
            holder.attchmt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attach_txt);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }

        else
        {
            holder=(VHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }
        String d=child_obj.getT_name();
        holder.date.setText(d);
        String loc_con1=child_obj.getSub();

        holder.loc.setText(loc_con1);
        String m=child_obj.getDate();
        holder.mesg.setText(m);
        String a=child_obj.getAttachment();
        holder.attchmt.setText(a);
        return convertView;



/*
        Child child = (Child) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_list_item, null);
        }



        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.country_name);


        tv.setText(child.getName().toString());


        return convertView;*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
       /* ArrayList<Child> chList = groups.get(groupPosition).getItems();
        return chList.size();*/

        return child.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Parent_Bean getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Parent_Bean group_obj=(Parent_Bean) getGroup(groupPosition);

        VHolder hlder=null;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group2,null);
            hlder=new VHolder();
            hlder.titl=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title_txt);

            convertView.setTag(hlder);
        }
        else
        {
            hlder=(VHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }





        hlder.titl.setText(group_obj.getTitle_b());

        /*Group1 group = (Group1) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.calendar_list_group, null);
        }
        TextView tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_name);
        tv.setText(group.getName());*/
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    private class VHolder {
        TextView date,loc,mesg,attchmt,titl;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change to

```
@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).getItems().get(childPosition);   
}
```

Might work

Comment: Please explanation on your answer.